# Specific row view using mysql or php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing an announcement system where the admin will just post some announcement and post it.and users will just log in and see the list of the announcement... I don't have any problem when storing it into the database or viewing the announcement title by order by date using PHP. The problem is when I will view/click the specific announcement it can't view the real one but it will view the recent data in the databases.

the announcement column consists of `a_title, a_date, a_description,a_ID,employee_type`.

Employee type can be admin1,admin2,admin3.

for example

```
  |DATE|----------|ANNOUNCEMENT title|

2017-01-22          announcement1      click to view
2017-01-22          announcement2      click to view
2017-01-22          announcement3      click to view
2017-01-22          announcement4      click to view
```

when I click the "click here to view" it should show the announcement title and the announcement about.

is there a way to view the specific announcement row in a simple way? for example using MySQL queries?

hope you could help me with this

Comment: You can see the announcement by fetching a data by the id of each data. Make an anchor and put the id in the 'href' and on the view fetch data of that selected id and view as you want.

Answer (score 0):

On "click to view" set the `<a href="yourpath?anno_id=1">` and then clicking on it will go to db with id, get the details and show on other page.

Comment: so i need to use some java script to do it?

Comment: no... just add link to "click to view" which gets the id of particular announcement & then go to database to get all details of announcement using that id & then echo on other page...

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the id of the announcement in the Anchor tag. 
If you showing a table then in the last column you give this anchor tag.

```
<td> <a> </a> </td>
```

Now in the Anchor tag do as given below.

```
$yourAnnoucementID = $row['yourAnnoucementID']
<a href="single_annoucemnt.php?id=<?php echo $yourAnnoucementID ?>"> View Single Annoucement </a>
```

On the single_annoucemnt.php page

```
if(isset($_GET['id']){
$yourAnnoucementId = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($yourAnnoucementId);
$query = "SELECT announcement FORM your_table WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Hope You can go ahead from here by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

your "click to view" must contains the a_ID of your announcement.

Here's how to do it:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>DATE</th>
   <th>ANNOUNCEMENT TITLE</th>
   <th>ACTION</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $date?></td>
   <td><?php echo $announcement?></td>
   <td><a href="view_announcement.php&id=<?php echo $a_ID?>">CLICK TO VIEW</a></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```